# how do I put the focus back on the last cell edited?

Tags: c#, datagridview, .net-4.0

I am saving my bound datagridview and on the event, I'm am saving the record with this method:

```
void dataGridView1_RowValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
  Entity.SaveChanges();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Error while saving. Check the current row for errors.{0}{0}Exception:{0}{0}{1}", Environment.NewLine, ex.Message));
   // I'd like to push it back to the last cell edited here
  }
}
```

If an exception occurred, I'd like to push the users focus back to the last cell edited. Is this possible?

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
string tbname;    
void dataGridView1_RowValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   try
{      
     Entity.SaveChanges();
     tbname = Entity.Accessible.Name;        //save the name of the last edit textbox       
}

 catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Error while saving. Check the current row for errors.{0}{0}Exception:{0}{0}{1}", Environment.NewLine, ex.Message));

     tbname.focus();               //will return the focus to that textbox last edited    
  }
}
```